# What is the reason behind the weight updates in Evolution Strategies?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, evolutionary-algorithms

OpenAI introduced [Evolution Strategies](https://openai.com/blog/evolution-strategies/) as an alternative to reinforcement learning technique without backpropagation. A sample code from their website,

```
# simple example: minimize a quadratic around some solution point
import numpy as np
solution = np.array([0.5, 0.1, -0.3])
def f(w): return -np.sum((w - solution)**2)

npop = 50      # population size
sigma = 0.1    # noise standard deviation
alpha = 0.001  # learning rate
w = np.random.randn(3) # initial guess
for i in range(300):
  N = np.random.randn(npop, 3)
  R = np.zeros(npop)
  for j in range(npop):
    w_try = w + sigma*N[j]
    R[j] = f(w_try)
  A = (R - np.mean(R)) / np.std(R)
  w = w + alpha/(npop*sigma) * np.dot(N.T, A)
```

I know how a genetic algorithm works but in Evolution Strategies they use some way to nudge the weights to a solution. In backpropagation we use gradients to update weights but in ES I really dont understand
the reason behind weight updates. The problem is in these lines

```
  w_try = w + sigma*N[j]
  R[j] = f(w_try)
  A = (R - np.mean(R)) / np.std(R)
  w = w + alpha/(npop*sigma) * np.dot(N.T, A)
```

I assume `f` is a fitness function and `R` the list of fitness values corresponding to the probable solutions. But I dont understand the reason behind `w + sigma*N[j]`, `(R - np.mean(R)) / np.std(R)` and most importantly `w + alpha/(npop*sigma) * np.dot(N.T, A)`. What is the reason behind nudging weights using `w + alpha/(npop*sigma) * np.dot(N.T, A)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w + sigma*N[j]`

this perturbs the weights `w` to give all the "offspring"

`(R - np.mean(R)) / np.std(R)`

just normalizing the rewards -- a fairly common hack in RL

`w + alpha/(npop*sigma) * np.dot(N.T, A)`

this is explained in the paper. in short, this is *the gradient of the expected fitness of the population*.